# Is it possible to use Logitech c310 webcam full-featured?

Tags: webcam, logitech

Through the software Cheese or other softwares in the Software Center, I can't take photos with the resolution 5 mega-pixels, can't use motion-detect,pan,tilt and zoom.Is it possible to use these c310's features under Ubuntu? 
I think, the reason why I can't use is related to the driver linux uses, not to the softwares.Therefore, is there any other driver for linux to use the c310's features especially taking 5mp photos?

Comment: Uhm... this [C310 camera](http://www.logitech.com/assets/30132/4/logitech-hd-webcam-c310.png) does not feature any zoom. It has a fixed lens. Likewise for panning/tilting (it is just a simple fixed camera!). Motion detection is a software feature which might be available in some other software which is Logitech-specific on Windows. 5MP pictures are also fake: software interpolation by Logitech on Windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind No, that's not needed anymore. C310/C510 cameras work out of the box nowadays (ever sinds 12.04 if I'm correct)!

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but is there a way to determine (hopefully before buying - a website or something) what the native resolution of these cameras might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Don't be fooled by the specs.

This camera does not have the features you mention. And don't be fooled by the specs [Logitech provides](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c310) you. It's all *software*.

E.g.:

> Photos: Up to 5 megapixels (software enhanced)

The camera's sensor is just 1280x720, so good luck in taking 5MP pictures. It'll just be a fuzzy blown up thing in Windows.

> Logitech webcam software:
>
> - Pan, tilt, and zoom controls
> - Video and photo capture
> - Face tracking
> - Motion detection

This is all just software enhancements as well (fake!). It does not have a zoom lens, it does not have a servo motor to pan/tilt, it does not move on face movements, etc.

Comment: I had realized before but I forgot that it is software enhanced.The other features, actually the camera looks like(physically) it is able to zoom,pan/tilt. http://www.logitech.com/assets/30132/logitech-hd-webcam-c310.png However, the appearance is just to fool people.